# How to decode this text and display it as Arabic?

Tags: html, decode, arabic

I have some text in a database that is encoded in some way, but I don't know what exactly, and the person who built the database and website left no documentation or comments of any kind. Ask an example, ÌÈÑÇä-1914 is stored in the database, but on the website, it is displayed as جبران-1914. How do I decode ÌÈÑÇä-1914 in order to get the Arabic text?

I've tried decoding ÌÈÑÇä-1914 into windows-1256, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, but when I put it in an html file and lang-eg in the html tag, and meta charset=utf-8, but nothing is letting me display it as Arabic text instead of some indecipherable characters. How can I convert the encoded text into Arabic?

Comment: Please provide an example document. Have you set the document / container element to dir='rtl' lang='ar'?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html dir = "rtl" lang="ar">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<p> ÌÈÑÇä-1914 </p>
</html> is what I was using, it still displays ÌÈÑÇä-1914, and if you use the google translate popup it translates it incorrectly.

Comment: `python -c print('ÌÈÑÇä'.encode('cp1252').decode('CP1256'))` returns `جبران` (and you could apply this principle in any scripting language).

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem was that I was exporting the data incorrectly--when I exported it as ISO 8859-2 and converting it to windows 1256 in atom it displayed properly.